# How to convert an object properties into an array in php

Tags: php, laravel

**Those data in `$data` variable. When I'm using `dd($data);` I got this:**

```
   CurlHandle {#1918 ▼
      +url: "https://example.com"
      +content_type: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      +http_code: 200
      +header_size: 887
      +namelookup_time_us: 139522
      +pretransfer_time_us: 326662
      +redirect_time_us: 0
      +starttransfer_time_us: 668686
      +total_time_us: 668752
    }
```

I want to convert this data to an array.
I'm using this: `$arr = json_decode($data,true);`

**But, this is not working. Now, how can I convert this?**

Comment: what is the type of this, is it a PHP object, please use `var_dump($yourObject)` and tell me the result

Comment: I got this  `object(CurlHandle)#1918 (0) { }`

Comment: What is the result of `json_decode($data,true);`? Do you have any types of error?

Comment: `json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, CurlHandle given`  this error I got.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are, in PHP, maybe iterable. Notice, you may iterate through an object's **public fields** only via the `foreach` loop. So the following works:

```
$array = [];

foreach ($object as $property) {
    $array[] = $property; // Stores public field only
}

var_dump($array);
```

Simply to get an array of object properties, you may use the `get_object_vars()` function.

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($object));
```

You may cast an object to be an array as @MoussabKbeisy said. And this would be the easiest way:

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

Here is another way is using `ArrayIterator`:

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($object);

var_dump(iterator_to_array($iterator));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution

```
$yourArray = json_decode(json_encode($yourObject), true);
```

and this [convert object to an array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/convert-object-to-an-array-in-php) for more info

Answer (score -1):

while this is a `PHP Object` so you can deal with it by 2 ways: 
**1- if you want to get on of it's parameters, you can simply use**

```php
$yourObject->parameter;
```

**2- if you need to use convert and use it as array, then there is different ways to convert an object to an array in PHP**

```php
//1
$array = (array) $yourObject;

//2
$array = json_decode(json_encode($yourObject), true);
```

Also see this in-depth blog post:

[Fast PHP Object to Array conversion](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/fast-php-object-to-array-conversion/)